# Python - Pandas - in Dataframe insert more than one value to a column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample data of a dataframe:

```
df:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'value', 'sum'])
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|     | id  | value | sum  |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 1   | 115 | 4     | 6    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 2   | 115 | 23    | 57   |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 3   | 18  | 143   | 253  |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 4   | 18  | 5     | 9    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 5   | 22  | 86    | 144  |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 6   | 22  | 104   | 209  |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 7   | 22  | 909   | 2132 |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| ... | ... | ...   | ...  |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
```

It gives me output like this in json:

```
df = {'115': [4, 6], '115': [23, 57], '18': [143, 253], '18': [5, 9], 
      '22': [86, 144], '22': [104, 209], '22': [909, 2132], ...  }
```

I would like to combine values of the same id like below in another dataframe:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'total'])

+-----+-----+----------------------------------+
|     | id  | total                            |
+-----+-----+----------------------------------+
| 1   | 115 | [4, 6] [23, 57]                  |
+-----+-----+----------------------------------+
| 3   | 18  | [143, 254] [5, 9]                |
+-----+-----+----------------------------------+
| 5   | 22  | [86, 144] [104, 209] [909, 3132] |
+-----+-----+----------------------------------+
| ... | ... | ...                              |
+-----+-----+----------------------------------+

dft = {'115': [[4, 6], [23, 57]], '18': [[143, 253], [[5, 9]]
      '22': [[86, 144], [104, 209], [909, 2132]], ...  }
```

I tried the below code but it does not work:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'total'])
pid = 0    
for i in df['id']:
    if pid == df['id']:
        dft.loc[['id']] = df['id']
        dft.loc[['total']] = [ df[['id'],['value']] + df[['id'],['sum']] ]
        pid = df['index'][id] + 1

import json
with open('total.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(dft, fp)
```

It is not working and gives errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {1: 115, 2: 115, 3: 18, 4: 18, 5: 22, 6: 22, 7: 22},
 'value': {1: 4, 2: 23, 3: 143, 4: 5, 5: 86, 6: 104, 7: 909},
 'sum': {1: 6, 2: 57, 3: 253, 4: 9, 5: 144, 6: 209, 7: 2132}})

df['total'] = df.set_index('id').values.tolist()
df = df.groupby('id')['total'].apply(list).reset_index()

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dict(zip(df.id,df.total)), f)
```

Output

```
'{"18": [[143, 253], [5, 9]], "22": [[86, 144], [104, 209], [909, 2132]], "115": [[4, 6], [23, 57]]}'
```